# Google Analytics custom user properties

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, google-analytics, office365

I have created an app for SharePoint Online that adds Google Analytics to our site and all it's pages to bridge the gap that you cannot pull this data via audit reports like an on premises installation. I can see data flowing into analytics without an issue. The problem comes in when I'm looking for the user information in Analytics. I have set up a custom dimension and a custom metric, but I cannot see the data. I know it has to be something on the setup as the other generic data is working fine.

This is the setup:

Custom Dimension
[image]

Custom Metric
[image]

Analytics code

```
ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxx-y', 'auto');
ga('set', {
    'dimension1': _spPageContextInfo.userLoginName,
    'metric1': 1
});
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Call to analytics:

```
https://www.google-analytics.com/r/collect?v=1&_v=j40&a=673549611&t=pageview&_s=1&dl=https%3A%2F%2Ftenant.sharepoint.com%2Fsites%2Fsite%2FSitePages%2FHome.aspx&ul=en-us&de=UTF-8&dt=Home&sd=24-bit&sr=1920x1080&vp=1610x991&je=0&fl=19.0%20r0&_u=QACAAEABI~&jid=369651474&cid=2614006.1448315161&tid=UA-xxxxxxx-y&_r=1&cd1=email.address%40domain.com&cm1=1&z=61973351
```

So I can see it is sending over the data correctly, I can't understand how/why/where the configuration within Analytics is to see this data.

Comment: Custom Dimensions/Metrics are not part of the standard reports, you can select them (after allowing for some 24 hours of processing time) in custom reports or by selecting them as secondary dimension in your Behavior reports (at least it makes most sense in Behavior, seeing that this is hit level data).

Comment: This has been in place for a few days now (since Thursday last week).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately I ended up adapting my code to log all the things I could think of.

```
ga('set', {'dimension1': _spPageContextInfo.userLoginName, 'metric1': 1, '&uid': _spPageContextInfo.userLoginName});
```

Multiple iterations over several days did not start logging data.